# Sending data to a method registered for a notification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, selector, nsnotifications

I need to pass some data to a method which I am registering to execute once I receive a notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:withCell:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Here I want to send some data for withCell part of my method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. You're registering for a notification and you can't control what is sent with that notification.

What is it you would like to do?

Comment: With this notification, I want to scroll my table view to the selected cell. So, I need to add keyboard height in the contentSet of table view. Now in the notification call back I have my table view but not the index of the selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

When you're posting notification and want to pass some data use:

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

but this is system notification in your case, so the best choice for you would be registering callback in your view controller that would be called when keyboard is shown (it receives only one parameter - NSNotification). You'll have to use some ivar (e.g. selectedCell) and process it in that callback.